# How to restore screen after jumping back?

Tags: jumplist

Say my cursor is in the middle of the screen and I jumped with `gg` and then jumping back with `C-o` or maybe other jumping command (like using marks). What happens now is that line that have been in the centre of the screen would be at the bottom or at the start. I'd like it to be at the same screen position it was before jump.

Comment: Christian's answer is correct, however, I think using `zz`, `zt`, `z-`, etc after a jump can be a nice workaround which can be faster than using the views see [`:h scroll-cursor`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/scroll.txt.html#scroll-cursor).

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `winsaveview()` and `winrestview()` functions, to correctly restore the last saved view. However, there is no easy way to have this done automatically restore a view after a jump or so. You would have to do some Vim Scripting to have this work for you.